# Background color of the particular cell is not changing after clicking specific cells in qTableWidget pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qtablewidget

So I have a table with 1 row and multiple columns and I use the custom delegate function for the image thumbnail. I also included the set background colour function when I click it. However, it doesn't change the colour of the item background. I have to use the custom delegate function so that my icon image is sticking with each other from different cell without any additional spaces between.

my code is as below

```
import random

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


imagePath2 = "arrowREDHead.png"
imagePath = "arrowREDBody.png"
class IconDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        icon = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
        mode = QtGui.QIcon.Normal
        if not (option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Enabled):
            mode = QtGui.QIcon.Disabled
        elif option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
            mode = QtGui.QIcon.Selected
        state = (
            QtGui.QIcon.On
            if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open
            else QtGui.QIcon.Off
        )
        pixmap = icon.pixmap(option.rect.size(), mode, state)
        painter.drawPixmap(option.rect, pixmap)

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        return QtCore.QSize(20, 20)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(1, 10)
        delegate = IconDelegate(table)
        table.setItemDelegate(delegate)

        self.setCentralWidget(table)

        for j in range(table.columnCount()):

            if(j % 2 == 0):

                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath)
                icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)

                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                it.setIcon(icon)
                table.setItem(0, j, it)
            
            else:
                pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath2)
                icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                it.setIcon(icon)
                table.setItem(0, j, it)
                table.item(0, 1).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(100,100,150))

                
        table.resizeRowsToContents()
        table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        table.setShowGrid(False)
        table.itemClicked.connect(self.sequenceClicked)

    def sequenceClicked(self, item): 
        self.itemClicked = item
        print("item", item)
        item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(255, 215, 0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the image with the gap between icons and it form not a perfect looking arrow thats why I used the custom delegate function to stick the icon together and let it look like a perfect arrow

[image: First image]

This is the image that has the perfect look of the arrow as it doesnt has any gap between the cells by using the delegate function. However, it doesnt allow me to change the background colour for the cell.

[image: Second image]

This is the image of the arrowHead

[image: arrowHead]

This is the image of the arrowBody

[image: arrowBody]

Comment: You're completely overriding the painting of the item, as right now you only paint the pixmap, and ignoring anything else. It's also a bit unclear your explanation for the paint override: what do you mean by "so that my icon image is sticking with each other from different cell"? Can you provide the example images you're using so that we can better understand?

Comment: I have added two images above. the first image shows the reason why I have to use the delegate function as there is a gap between so that it can override the cell padding and turn it into the arrow without any gap as in image 2. However, is there any possible way to somehow change the background colour of the cell when click even after I override it with the delegate function?

Comment: Having the *actual* images is what would help, as the problem is probably related to their aspect ratio.

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what u meant, do u want to see the actual images or? Because I have tried setting different aspect ratio of the images using setIconsize and even set its scaling but it doesn't work. That is why I use the custom delegate function but the problem is I wanted to implement the change colour of the particular cell when I click but I could'nt think of a way to do so using the delegate function

Comment: I meant the arrow images. I can provide a solution, but having those images would be better to ensure that it properly works as you'd expect. Depending on the OS and style, items can be drawn in very different ways, and decorations (the icons) can have different margins and alignments. There are various possible approaches, but the better ones are those that mostly use the default implementation, so having those images is essential, especially if they don't have the same size or ratio, because proper alignment is mandatory for your case.

Comment: I have added the original images I used the arrowHead and arrowBody which I insert it inside the cell which form a complete arrow. Both these images are the same aspect ratio. However, it doesnt able to connect with each other as an arrow for the first output result images. But I will also have to change the background of the cell when I clicked a certain cell in the table and it will remain as the changed color if I select another cell again which i am not being able to implement.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you expect those images to always *stretch* (for instance, if the column is resized)?

Comment: I plan to make the column not to be allowed to be resized anyway there is just a fixed column that all column will be the same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any overridden function, if the base implementation is not called, the default behavior is ignored.

`paint()` is the function responsible of drawing any aspect of the item, including its background. Since in your override you are just drawing the pixmap, everything else is missing, so the solution would be to call the base implementation and *then* draw the pixmap.

In this specific case, though, this wouldn't be the right choice, as the base implementation already draws the item's decoration, and in certain conditions (assuming that the pixmap has an alpha channel), it will probably result in having the images overlapping.

There are three possible solutions.

### Use QStyle functions ignoring the icon

In this case, we do what the base implementation would, which is calling the style `drawControl` function with the `CE_ItemViewItem`, but we modify the option before that, removing anything related to the icon:

```
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        # create a new option (as the existing one should not be modified)
        # and initialize it for the current index
        option = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(option, index)

        # remove anything related to the icon
        option.features &= ~option.HasDecoration
        option.decorationSize = QtCore.QSize()
        option.icon = QtGui.QIcon()

        if option.widget:
            style = option.widget.style()
        else:
            style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
        # call the drawing function for view items
        style.drawControl(style.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter, option.widget)

        # proceed with the custom drawing of the pixmap
        icon = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
        # ...
```

### Update the icon information in the delegate

A QStyledItemDelegate always calls [`initStyleOption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#initStyleOption) at the beginning of most its functions, including `paint` and `sizeHint`. By overriding that function, we can change some aspects of the drawing, including the icon alignment and positioning.

In this specific case, knowing that we have only two types of icons, and they must be right or left aligned depending on the image, it's enough to update the proper decoration size (based on the optimal size of the icon), and then the alignment based on the column.

```
class IconDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.decorationSize = option.icon.actualSize(option.rect.size())
        if index.column() & 1:
            option.decorationPosition = option.Left
            option.decorationAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
        else:
            option.decorationPosition = option.Right
            option.decorationAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter
```

Note: this approach only works as long as the images all have the same ratio, and the row height is not manually changed.

### Use a custom *role* for the image

Qt uses *roles* to store and retrieve various aspects of each index (font, background, etc.), and *user* roles can be defined to store custom data.

`setIcon()` actually sets a QIcon in the item using the `DecorationRole`, and the delegate uses it to draw it. If the data returned for that role is empty/invalid, no icon is drawn.

If we don't use `setIcon()` but store the icon in the item with a custom role instead, the default drawing functions will obviously not draw any decoration, but we can still access it from the delegate.

```
# we usually define roles right after the imports, as they're constants
ImageRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1

class IconDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super().paint(painter, option, index)
        icon = index.data(ImageRole)
        # ...

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                it.setData(ImageRole, pixmap)
```